# Google Calendars set to Auto-Accept any invitation are rejecting all invitations created by http request

Tags: calendar, google-api, httprequest, google-calendar-api

I have two google calendars that I am trying to add events to programmatically through HTTP requests. I happen to be using iOS HTTP library, but I imaging that's largely irrelevant.

Both http requests are coming back as successes, but one calendar is declining the invitation.

It appears to me that they are both set up the same way, although I don't have admin access to them.

Is this more likely a calendar configuration problem that I can't see or is this an HTTP request problem?

Does anyone know the proper configuration settings for the calendars?

Edit: I asked for and received admin access to a pair of calendars, one that works one that does not. Both calendars have the "See all event details" preference selected

Comment: Is the calendar(which is rejecting the invitations) is shared with you? check this link https://support.google.com/a/answer/1084813?hl=en

Comment: @SGC I was hoping that would work. Unfortunately I just got admin access to a pair of calendars, one that works one that does not and both are set to the "See all event details" recommended by the answer.